# Using global variables in node js in different async functions

Tags: node.js, global-variables, node-modules, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to get more familiar with best practices in NodeJS. Currently, I have a asynchronous function that scrapes some data off a website and stores the values retrieved in an object. What I would like to do, is use the value in a different function to extract data from Yahoo Finance to retrieve specific values. I am unsure how to pass in this value to the other functions. I'm thinking possibly setting the value, that is passed in to to other functions, as a global variable. Would that be best practice in the NodeJS world of programming? Any opinions or advice would helpful. Below is the code I currently have:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const axios = require("axios");
 
async function read_fortune_500() {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios({ method: "GET", url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies", })
    const $ = cheerio.load(data)
    const elemSelector = '#constituents > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1)'
    const keys = ['symbol']

    $(elemSelector).each((parentIndex, parentElem) => {
      let keyIndex = 0
      const stockObject = {}
      if (parentIndex <= 9){
      $(parentElem).children().each((childIndex, childElem) => {
        const tdValue = $(childElem).text()

        if (tdValue) {
          stockObject[keys[keyIndex]] = tdValue
        }
      })
      console.log(stockObject)
    }
    })
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}

async function getCurrentPrice() {}

read_fortune_500()
```

Comment: function 1 returns a value, that return value is passed to function 2 as an argument. What am I missing, why are there global variables needed?

Comment: thank you. You're likely not missing anything.

Comment: Globals would NOT be a best practice in nodejs.  Besides the challenges/conflicts with modularity, it also opens you up to concurrency issues in a multi-user server.  Note that VLAZ's suggestion is probably overly simplistic here since these are asynchronous functions, you cannot return the values directly.  Instead, you probably return a promise which resolves to the asynchronous value and the caller uses `.then()` or `await` to retrieve the desired value and then passes that to the next function in the asynchronous chain.

Comment: FYI, as with all questions here about code, if you include your actual code, we can provide very specific answers that would apply to your exact situation.  In fact, if you had done so when you posted your question, you would probably already have several answers for suggested code for you specific situation.  You can still add that code to your question.

Comment: @jfriend00, that's a good point. I have updated with code.

Comment: So, in that code what data are you trying to pass to what function?

Comment: the values of the stockObject variable I am trying to pass into another function, getCurrentPrice.

Comment: Can you describe more of the whole problem because `stockObject` is acquired inside a loop and how you call an asynchronous function like `getCurrentPrice()` inside a loop depends upon what you're trying to do with the result.  At a minimum, you can just call `getCurrentPrice(stockObject)` from right where your `console.log(stockObject)` is.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds more like a JavaScript question then a NodeJS specific question.

NodeJS: I would say you can store the result of scraping the website in session data. Or pass it along in the response and call next(). Or create some middleware to scrape the website before calling the Yahoo route.

Javascript:  You can call a async function to scrape the data on your site and await the response. once it is done you can call your next function passing the data retrieved from async result. See below for basic example.

```js
async function scrapeWebsite(){
    let webScrapeReults;
    // logic to scrape site
    return webScrapeReults;
}

 function getYahooMarket(){
    let results;
    let webData = await scrapeWebsite();
    // use webData to get reults for yahooMarket
    return results;
}
```